# Connect a portable USB modem (data card) with Samsung Galaxy S II

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, usb-modem

Is it possible to connect and use portable USB modems such as Reliance net connect, MTS, etc., using an [OTG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) cable with [Samsung Galaxy S II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II) and use it?

I went through many forums and haven't got any promising answer. I'm currently using Android version 4.0.3 along with [SiyahKernel](http://www.gokhanmoral.com/) 3.0. In this kernel, I'm able to connect flash drives, mouse and keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to say with absolute certainty, but generally speaking that is not possible. Some devices can be patched and hacked to include support for this, but I am not aware of one for the Samsung Galaxy S II on any kernel. The flash drive, mouse and keyboard support is built-in to Android whereas USB network dongles need to be hacked on to it. I know it is possible on a number of Nvidia platfoms to connect Huawei USB dongles, but on the Samsung gear, I've never seen a way.

In short, that's not known to be possible on the Samsung Galaxy S II [ICS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing).

Comment: Even though this is not the answer I was expecting, thank you so much for your effort and answering.

Comment: Hi Peter, can you suggest us the tablet and dongle models, which are compatible?

Answer (score 2):

If you can build and install a modified kernel (or perhaps just drivers) and root filesystem, and there exists driver source to use these on a desktop linux, then it should be possible.

You might be able to re-write the driver to function via the USB host APIs without root, but it would probably take root level access to get the result seen as a network interface.  Though without that you might still be able to make an on-device proxy server to get a browser to use it.