# How to use usb modem to connect to Internet on Sony Xperia Z Ultra running Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, usb, internet, sony-xperia-z, usb-modem

I have a `Tata Photon+` internet usb modem. But I am not able to access internet through it when connected my device. Whenever I connect the modem to my android device nothing shows up that you are connected to modem's internet.  I connect my modem using my `micro-usb` converter. I watched some videos on YouTube but they all had a rooted method to connect to Internet. I have `Sony Xperia Z Ultra` with `Android Lollipop 5.0.1`. So if somebody has a technique to connect USB modem to my android device please answer.

Comment: Quick google search yielded this. Give this a shot. http://mytabletguru.com/steps-to-connect-dongle-to-android-tablet/ 

Let us know if it works for you or not.

Comment: @jer3my Consider developing a brief context around the link (even if it is a comment) so that if the link expires in future, a reader can at least come to know what the link intended to tell.

Comment: [This answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/25115/27149) might help.

Comment: @Firelord Good Idea. ---- Its recommended to plug in the dongle and wait 5-10 mins as some tablets will auto create the APN settings. Its also recommended that you disable sleep mode for the time being. 

Then open Settings and find your Mobile Network, Then find Access Point Name. Then select New APN. Then fill in Name/APN/Dial Number. Set the network name. You can name it whatever you like. Then set the APN. You will have to search for the service provider's APN settings. 

--- Taken from the link in my other comment.

Comment: But i have all option in my new apn settings except the dial number setting